# How to extract .xml file from .docx?

Tags: xml, docx

I recently learned that I can extract an .xml file from a .docx by renaming the file to .zip and opening the .zip file.

However, when I do this, I just get .docx document again. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Can someone help me understand how to get the .xml from the .docx?

I have tried on a Mac and Windows and have the same problem.

Comment: You do understand that the XML file is not usable by itself.

Comment: Yes, I am hoping to use R to extract some information from the word document. It may not work but it is an option I'm exploring at the moment.

Comment: You might use [DocRipper](https://github.com/pzaich/doc_ripper).

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to rename the DOCX file. Just open it.

I opened a couple of DOCX files with WinZip by navigating to the folder, and selecting ALL files in the Open File dialogue in WinZip.

It opened the file and showed me the XML files and extracted them.

You can also use 7-Zip for this.

[Unzip DOCX with 7-Zip](https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/thread/ef313ab1/)

> I opened a 7z file containing an XML file and tried to double click on
> it and got the same error as you (becuase the temp file is deleted
> BEFORE Internet Explorer starts).
>
> I then reassociated XML files with first Windows Notepad and then
> FireFox and had no problem viewing the opened XML file in either of
> them (because the temp file wasn't deleted until AFTER Notepad/FireFox
> were closed).

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have WinZip

Comment: Try z-Zip  https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/thread/ef313ab1/   Also look for specific products that can do this. I saw a number of these using Google to search. You may need a different product but you can extract the files.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac you need to change the extension, then open it with something 'smarter' than the built-in archiver.

[Keka](https://www.keka.io/en/) is a freeware* multi-archive extractor which will 'unzip' it into its component parts.

*In effect, it's donationware. Free to download direct, 3.99 on the App Store.

Comment: I still have the same problem. I tried using Keka, but when I unzip it, I still only have the .docx file. 
I have tried on a PC and Mac, and I've tried using a mostly empty trial document and a real document.

Comment: test with the docx file on here - https://file-examples.com/index.php/sample-documents-download/sample-doc-download/ - the 100k That's what I tested with. Change the extension, then right click, Open With > Keka.

Comment: If you really need to extract these files, WinZip comes for both PC and MAC. You could consider a trial on the PC platform.

Comment: @John - it's not normally necessary to jump through hoops like this. It's because Windows can't use packages that MS have to do it this way. Apple would normally be fully prepared for this type of structure as a package, but because MS have to artificially fold it into a zip to make it look like a file rather than the folder it actually is, it leaves the Mac a bit stumped what to do with it. If you compare to a very similar doc type, Pages, then all you'd need to do would be right-click, show package contents. Then you can poke around inside without ever actually touching the package itself.